# window.opener.closepopup(url) not working in java

Tags: java, jsp

I m closing the pop up window opened in jsp on click of submit.jsp is containing a form.On submitting it throws object cant support the property clospopup.
Following is the jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/tiles.tld" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Configure</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/css1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/css2.css" />
<script>

    function fnSaveData(){

        //var vPlanType = document.getElementById("planType").value;
        var description=document.getElementById("description").value;



        var url = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/class.do?operation=save&description="+description;

        window.opener.closepopup(url);
    }


</script>
</head>
<body>



<table  cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0 width="100%" height="100%" > 
<form name="cpReportGenerationForm" method="post" >
<tr  height="20" bgcolor='#FEE8C6'>
            <td class='dpFontText' height=20px align="center" colspan="2">
                <strong>
                    Configuration
            </strong>
            </td> 
        </tr>
     <tr height="15px">
     </tr>

    <tr valign="top">
<td>

    <table align="center" class="FPinnertable" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0 width="95%"  border=0>
     <tr valign="top">
        <td>

         <table class="dpDataTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" valign="top" id="tableData">

          <tr class="odd">
           <td width="20%" class="shadedColoumn">Grid Description&nbsp;</td>
                       <td width="20%" class="whiteColoumn">
                        <input type="text" id = "description" Class="ArmsselectionCriteriaElement" style="width:160px" />
                       </td>
           </tr>

        <tr valign=top> 

                        <td align="center">
                            <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add" type="button" class ="ArmsSaveAndRefreshButton" onClick="javascript:fnSaveData();" >
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Please  help me in correcting the error.

Comment: Hi. I think you will get better help if you rephrase your question and title and maybe alter the tags on it.  The line you ask about ` window.opener.closepopup(url);` appears to be in plain Javascript, so not Java or JSP.  It's also not immediately clear why you're expecting `window.opener`, which returns a window object, to support `closepopup` ?

Comment: i m closing the popup up and redirecting the window to other url